# VBA: Convert byte array into Image without saving it temporary

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got a decoded byte array from base64 (I needed this so I could send those bytes array via a XML file). 
Now, I have to "recompose" the image using the bytes array. I've searched for similar things and I've found resolution for VB code, but it's not compatible with VBA.

My code looks like this:

```
encodedImage = objXML.FirstChild.ChildNodes.Item(1).Text 'the encoded image in base64

' get array of bytes
Dim byteArr() As Byte
byteArr = DecodeBase64(encodedImage) 'this function decodes from base64 to bytes array

 Dim img As Image
```

The bytes array looks good because I've compared it with the imageData from the original image I want to recompose now.

Is there any way to do this conversion without saving the image temporary ?
After "recomposing" the image, I need to upload it in the word Document.

Comment: How about compiling a java program that does the job and running this program from vba?

Comment: It's not allowed in this case because of the task, just vba. The final solution was to temporary save the image, which isn't what I've really wanted to, but this will be a future fix. Thank you very much by now!!

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong, but I think there is a function in the System.IO.File library for the .NET framework that does what you are looking for and writes to a file path. I think it's called WriteAllBytes? You may need to import the library though. Hope this helps.

Comment: This concerns VBA not to be confused with VB.NET ;)